# Parse "Unexpected identifier in main.js" in my Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform

I am trying to deploy my newly written cloud code function to Parse but I keep getting the error "Unexpected identifier" at line 110, I can't seem to figure out how there is an error here, any help?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("backgroundJob", function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var moments = require("cloud/moments.js");

var now = moments.moment();
var groupObject = Parse.Object.extend("Group");
var query = new Parse.Query(groupObject);

var eventObject = Parse.Object.extend("Event");

query.find().then(function(groups) {
    var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
    _.each(group, function(result) {
        promise = promise.then(function() {
            var count = 0;
            var events = _.map(result.get("Events"), function(eventArray) {
                if (now == eventArray[count].get('date') {

                var curEvent = eventArray[count];
                eventArray[count].destory();

                var relationc = result.get("created");

                var createdq = relationc.query();

                var relationj = result.get("created");

                var joinedq = relationj.query();

                var partOnee = curEvent.get("name");
                var outString = partOnee.concat(" is now");

                Parse.Push.send({
                    where: createdq,
                    data: {
                        alert: outString
                    }
                }).then(function() {
                    response.success();
                }, function(error) {
                    response.error(error);
                });

                Parse.Push.send({
                    where: joinedq,
                    data: {
                        alert: outString
                    }
                }).then(function() {
                    response.success();
                }, function(error) {
                    response.error(error);
                });

                }

                count = count+1;
            });

        });
    });
}).then(function() {
    response.success()
}, function(error) {
    response.error(error);
});
});
```

Line 110 is ***var curEvent = eventArray[count];***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed `)` in this line `if (now == eventArray[count].get('date')`, see:

```
        var events = _.map(result.get("Events"), function(eventArray) {
            if (now == eventArray[count].get('date') {
```

Fix:

```
        var events = _.map(result.get("Events"), function(eventArray) {
            if (now == eventArray[count].get('date')) {
```

Note, when interpreters/compilers (in most programming languages) say there is a problem on a line, usually the problem can be in any row before.

Comment: Oh didn't catch that one, thanks. I assumed the error would be on that exact line.